# Restar en Stored Procedure MYSQL

Tags: mysql

quisiera que ver si me podían ayudar, ya tengo ratos de no trabajar con Mysql y tengo dificultades en este momento, necesito restar una cantidad y que se vaya acumulando, estoy haciendo esto en un stored procedure:

quiero que se muestre así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy comenzando mi SP y tengo esto:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `balance`(
    in pcliente int
)
BEGIN
    declare vmonto decimal(10,2);
    declare vcantidad decimal(10,2);
    SELECT cantidad + cantidad * porcentaje into vmonto FROM credito where cantidad>0 and id_cliente= pcliente;
    select 
        fecha, 
        if(cantidad>0,cantidad + cantidad * porcentaje,cantidad) cantidad,
        vmonto + cantidad monto
    from 
        credito 
    where 
        id_cliente=pcliente
        and id>=(select max(id) id from (SELECT * FROM credito where cantidad>0 and id_cliente=pcliente) a);
        
END
```

y como resultado me da esto:

'1380.00','2380.00'
'-60.00','1320.00'
'-60.00','1320.00'

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. Además, parecería que esto es algo propio de un TRIGGER (cuando ocurra una operación, que el TRIGGER se dispare y actualice el saldo).

Comment: Prodia ser, pero necesito mostrarla en una consulta, no como un dato que se almacena o actualiza

Comment: Se agradece un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable que incluya un set de datos. Con la información actual en la pregunta no es suficiente para entender el contexto y no es visible en base a qué datos son obtenidos los resultados que mencionas.

Comment: realmente pensé que incluso mostrando solo la tabla se podía entender, básicamente lo que quiero es que una variable almacene la resta de una columna y la vaya mostrando cambiando su valor. como se muestra en la tabla que coloqué de excel

Comment: Podrías usar SET por ejemplo para ir asignando el valor en cada cálculo. De todos modos no logro entender el contexto, ¿qué es lo que justifica esto?

Comment: como lo que quiero basicamente es restar cierta cantidad al saldo para formar un nuevo saldo, como según la tabla y el SP (si aplica) como se haría para poder tener el resultado de la tabla de excel?